# Dove si usa "barba" con il significato di "zio"?

Tags: word-usage, regional

Da quando ho letto il Canto XIX del *Paradiso* per la prima volta sono rimasta stupita dal fatto Dante usi il termine "barba" con il significato di zio (versi dal 136 al 138, grassetto mio):

> E parranno a ciascun l’opere sozze 
>          
> del **barba** e del fratel, che tanto egregia 
>          
> nazione e due corone han fatte bozze.

Personalmente, mi risulta anche interessante che sia l'«egregia nazione», siano le «due corone» facciano riferimento alla storia della mia terra (la casata di Barcellona e le corone di Aragona e di Maiorca). Ma la mia domanda è sul vocabolo "barba": l'uso che ne fa Dante mi è sembrato sorprendente perché con questa accezione l'avevo incontrato nel racconto *Argon* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, e pensavo fosse qualcosa di appartenente al gergo degli ebrei del Piemonte.   Ecco un brano di questo racconto a modo di esempio (grassetto sempre mio):

> Come sempre avviene, il rifiuto era reciproco: da parte della minoranza, una barriera simmetrica era stata eretta contro l’intera cristianità («gôjím», «ñarelím»: le «genti», i «non-circoncisi»), riproducendo, su scala provinciale e su di uno sfondo pacificamente bucolico, la situazione epica e biblica del popolo eletto. Di questo fondamentale sfasamento si alimentava l’arguzia bonaria dei nostri zii («**barba**») e delle nostre zie («magne»): savi patriarchi tabaccosi e domestiche regine della casa, che pure si autodefinivano orgogliosamente «’l pòpôl d’Israél».

Ho trovato questo termine con questo significato sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000060.jpg) con la marca "ant. e dial.". Quindi, sembra si usi ancora come dialettismo o perlomeno si usasse fino a poco tempo fa. Sapreste dirmi dove si usa "barba" con il significato di "zio"?

Comment: In Veneto si usa(va).

Comment: Non riguarda l'uso recente, ma è interessante quello che riporta in proposito l'Enciclopedia Dantesca Treccani: https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/barba_res-d62ecde0-87ee-11dc-8e9d-0016357eee51_%28Enciclopedia-Dantesca%29  (A Roma non si dice, per quel che vale.)

Comment: Grazie, @DaG. Ho potuto chiedere a un paio di toscani e m'hanno detto che neanche in Toscana si usa.

Comment: È comunemente usato nel dialetto piemontese, così come _magna_ per zia, e direi che non è limitato alla comunità ebraica piemontese (probabilmente Levi l'ha semplicemente preso dal piemontese). Da bambino l'ho sentito usare frequentemente tra parenti che parlavano piemontese. In [questo dizionario del 1869](https://www.piemunteis.it/wp-content/uploads/Pasquali_B.pdf) è presente.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: sembra che le informazioni di questo dizionario siano prese dal *Vocabolario degli Accademici della Crusca*. Questa è l'ultima edizione, in cui si dice "voce che vive tuttora in alcune parti d'Italia", ma immagino che questa affermazione faccia riferimento all'Ottocento o al primo Novecento: http://new.lessicografia.it/pagina/?vol=2&sez=2&ediz=5&pag=61. A quanto pare, perlomeno nel Settecento, si usava anche in Lombardia.

Comment: Confermo in toto ciò che dice @MassimoOrtolano: *barba* e *magna* sono usati, in Piemontese, per indicare zio e zia. Primo Levi, nei suoi libri, usa talvolta termini e costruzioni piemontesi.

Comment: Confermo quello che dice egreg: in Veneto si usava, anche se ormai tende a essere ristretto alle generazioni più vecchie. Leggermente più diffuso è *àmia* per zia.

Comment: Questo sito fornisce la traduzione dialettale di zio nelle varie regioni; sembra sia usato, o si usava in: Veneto, Emilia, Friuli, Liguria, Lombardia, Piemonte e Trentino. https://m.dialettando.com/dizionario/detail/?id=469 - in pratica come dice Garzanti “nelle regioni  settentrionali” https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=barba%202

Comment: @Hachi Confermo per la Lombardia: si usa(va).

Comment: Nei dialetti di Genova ed Imperia, quindi presumo di tutta la Liguria, zio=barba